# How to sort rows when sequence order does not match datetime order?

Tags: sql-server, session, sequence, teradata

I am trying to sessionize event data and found a case that breaks my query.

I have about 1300 machines that generate about 250k events per day. Each machine reports an EventCode, SequenceNumber ( 0 to 255 ), DateTime ( accurate to the second ), InAmount, OutAmount, RoundsCount.

My current code uses the LEAD(), LAG() functions ordering by DateTime to determine when a session starts and ends.  The issue I have found is sometimes the SequenceNumber is not in order vs the DateTime field.

Example data

```
>     +-----------+----------------+---------------------+----------+-----------+-------------+
>     | EventCode | SequenceNumber |      DateTime       | InAmount | OutAmount | RoundsCount |
>     +-----------+----------------+---------------------+----------+-----------+-------------+
>     |  10051300 |            198 | 2019-06-25 15:22:54 | 16779000 |  14814642 |      142483 |
>     |  10000100 |            182 | 2019-06-25 15:22:58 | 16770950 |  14809091 |      142321 |
>     |  10000901 |            200 | 2019-06-25 15:23:05 | 16779000 |  14814642 |      142483 |
>     |  13328100 |            201 | 2019-06-25 15:23:05 | 16779000 |  14814642 |      142483 |
>     |  13328500 |            202 | 2019-06-25 15:23:05 | 16779000 |  14814642 |      142483 |
>     |  10003505 |            199 | 2019-06-25 15:23:10 | 16779000 |  14814642 |      142483 |
>     |  10003503 |            204 | 2019-06-25 15:23:56 | 16779000 |  14814642 |      142483 |
>     +-----------+----------------+---------------------+----------+-----------+-------------+
```

SequenceNumber 182 and 199 are out of order when the data is ORDER BY DateTime.

I need to sort the data using the SequenceNumber, except the SequenceNumber goes from 0 to 255 multiple times per day and not every number is reported.

Comment: Why don't you `order by DateTime, SequenceNumber`?

Comment: I currently am doing a order by DateTime, SequenceNumber. The SequenceNumber 182 has a DateTime 4 seconds after SeqNum 198. I need the order to be 182 then 198 for this time period. The SeqNum cycled 3 times on that day

Comment: Is it possible that SequenceNumbers are missing, i.e. does SequenceNumber `0` always exist? Then you could assign all rows following `0` to a group and sort by SequenceNumber within that group. Btw, SQL Server or Teradata?

Comment: You could try sorting by RoundsCount, DateTime but 199 would still be out of order. Looks to me like you have insufficient data to sort the way you want to.

Does Sequence reset after certain time? You could try using some kind of process logic to help you with sorting, maybe round the date to nearest hour, eg ORDER BY DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, GETDATE()), 0), SequenceNumber..

Comment: I think you might be better off figuring out why your sequencing and timestamps aren't behaving consistently when the data is being generated.

Comment: I am using MSSQL 2008R2, 2012 and Teradata 15.10.  The 2008R2 system is the source ( has 35 days of data ), 2012 access the data via link connection, Teradata holds 12 years of data.  In this instance the SeqNum 182 is a reboot notification and 198 is a machine connected event. I'm starting to think I need to sessionize the data by DateTime, then order by SeqNum within each session to create a row number. Then use the row number to create the sessions using the LEAD() LAG() functions.